# convert pointer type in assignment

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that has:

```
private:
    uint32_t *data;
```

and the in one of the functions I'm doing:

```
void foo() {
    data = new uint32_t[size];
}
```

and that is working fine. Now i wanted to make it a bit more flexible, so i wanted to make foo() a template:

```
template<typename T>
T foo() {
    data = new T[size];
}
```

and i try to use it:

```
class.foo<uint64_t>();
```

But compilation fails saying that:

```
error: cannot convert 'long long unsigned int*' to 'unsigned int*' in assignment
```

Is it possible to do something like that? I tried declaring

```
void *data;
```

and it compiled, but then I cannot do

```
sizeof(data[1]);
```

which is essentially why I need to pass the type.

**EDIT:**

Thank you for your responses, there are a few thing I'd like to add after looking at your answers.

- I'm using raw pointer instead of container because it operates on memory that is used also by external hardware (I'm not running this on PC).
- Using this memory is optional for this class, so I don't want to allocate it if its not needed.
- I use this class in a few places where I don't need *data at all, so I'd rather avoid making the whole class a template.

Another thought:
Default template type might be a good compromise, is there a way to create a class that I won't have to later use that way:

```
Class<> my;
```

but still:

```
Class my;
```

and if needed:

```
Class<type> my;
```

?

Comment: what about T* data?

Comment: You need to convert the pointer-member to a `T*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider making your whole class a template, like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
private:
    T *data;
public:
    Foo(size_t size_):
        data{new T[size]}
    {
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }
};
```

Implementation is here only partial. See this about [rule of 3, 5, 0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Or using managed pointers:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> data;
    size_t size;
public:
    Foo(size_t size_):
        data{std::make_unique<T[]>(size_)},
        size(size_)
    {
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        // no need to call delete, unique_ptr will do it
    }
};
```

But once you're here, depending on your use case, alternatives may be preferable, like `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<uint64_t> v(size);
// ...
std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
```

**EDIT:**

From the additional information you provided, it looks like the following design may better suit your needs:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void* get_data() {
        return nullptr;
    }
    virtual size_t get_size() {
        return 0;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Foo : public Base
{
private:
    T* data;
    size_t size;
public:
    Foo(size_t size_):
        data{new T[size_]},
        size(size_) {}
    ~Foo() {
        delete[] this->data; // same remark as above about rule of 5
    }
    virtual void* get_data() overriden {
        return this->data;
    }
    virtual size_t get_size() overriden {
        return this->size;
    }
};
```

With the following usage:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> my_without_data =
    std::make_unique<Base>();

std::unique_ptr<Base> my_with_data =
    std::make_unique<Foo<type>>(size);
```

Note that in the second call, `std::make_unique` returns a `unique_ptr<Foo<type>>` with an appropriate deleter calling `Foo<type>`'s destructor. The deleter will be copied when assigning to `my_with_data` and call `Foo<type>`'s destructor even if `Base`'s destructor is not declared virtual.

I chose here a design with virtual methods in `Base` to access `data`. Depending on your real use case, other ways may be used.

Comment: I'll mark you answer as solution, but in fact default template value is I think the best I can do, although I was looking for something else.

Comment: @corwin I edited my answer with an other proposition. Tell me if it is more adapted to your case

Comment: OK, that is quite interesting, I think that may work, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than converting your function to a template, convert your class to a template:

```
template <class T>
class myclass {
private:
    T *data;
public:
    myclass(size_t size) : data(new T[size]) {
    }
    ... // Add copy constructor, assignment operator, and a destructor
        // to properly manage the pointer. See "rule of three" for more info.
};
```

This way the type of array element becomes part of the type of your class, letting your member functions work with the `data` without any additional type casting.

Note that using raw array pointer in the class comes with significant liabilities in terms of memory management. You would be better off with `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: Thank you, but I'd rather avoid this. Because using 'data' is an option for this class, so i don't want to allocate memory for it if I won't use it. What I need is create a class with some default type for 'data' and change it later.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your whole class to a templated class

```
template<typename T>
class Container {
public:
    Container() :
        data(NULL)
    {}
    ~Container() {
        if (data) {
            delete [] data;
        }
    }
    T* foo(int size) {
        if (data) {
            delete [] data;
        }
        data = new T[size];
        return data;
    }
private:
    T *data;
};
```